# Weird syntax error with array class

Tags: java, arrays

Im getting a syntax error with the semi at the end of my array and the last closing bracket. I've been banging my head over this for a bit. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
public class arrayWords {
    private Words wl;
    private String gamewords[];

    public arrayWords() {
        wl = new Words();
        gamewords = new String[] { "dog", "cat", "coffee", "tag", "godzilla", "gamera", "lightning", "flash",
                "spoon", "steak", "moonshine" };
        setArray();
    }

    public void setArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gamewords.length; i++)
            wl.wordList[i].setWord(gamewords[i]);
    }
}

public class Words {
    public Word wordList[];
    public Words() {
        super();
        wordList = new Word[25];
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            wordList[24] = new Word();
        }
    }
}

public class Word {

    String name;
    Words word = new Words();

    public Word() {
        super();
        name = new String("");
    }

    public Word(String w) {
        super();
        name = new String(w);
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setWord(String s) {
        this.name = new String(s);
    }

}

public class wordTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Words wl = new Words();
        arrayWords newArray = new arrayWords();

        newArray.setArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            System.out.println(wl.wordList[i].getWord());
    }
}
```

Comment: place your `for` loop in a method

Comment: Next time, please format your code, before pasting it here. Makes it more readable for everyone.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) { wordList[24] = new Word(); }` probably isn't doing what you want it to do.  Perhaps `i < 25` and `wordList[i] = ...`.

Comment: Also, `Word` constructs a `WordList` when it is constructed which then constructs 25 `Word`s so either class's constructor will blow out the stack.

Comment: What is a good way around this?

Comment: @JohnCasey did you just edit the question to put the answer in the question? Don't do that. If you do that, it looks like you never had a problem.

Comment: I didn't edit anything.

Comment: I did make the suggested changes, but then I saw the comment about the constructors.

Comment: I made a mistake. Originally, i had 25 words in the array, I forgot that I reduced it to 11 for testing purposes.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what I did. I was asked to update the main question because it was hard to read as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't the array. You are trying to run a for-loop right inside the class. This should be done in either a method or the main-method.

**Edit**:

An example of what you might want:

```
public class ArrayWords {
private Words wl;
private String gamewords[];

public ArrayWords() {
    wl = new Words();
    gamewords = new String[] { "dog", "cat", "coffee", "tag", "godzilla", "gamera", "lightning", "flash", "spoon", "steak", "moonshine" };
    setArray();
}

public void setArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gamewords.length; i++)
        wl.wordList[i].setWord(gamewords[i]);
}

// getters and setters
}
```

Now you can simply have a class with a main-method and initialize it as

```
ArrayWords arrayWords = new ArrayWords();
arrayWords...... // what you want to do
```

Comment: Could i just write a set method? void setArray(){
 for (int i=0; i<gamewords.length; i++)
     wl.wordList[i].setWord(gamewords[i]);
     
    }

Comment: Given that the full code is not provided, it's hard for me to determin where it best fits in. But surely, you can have a method like you mentioned and call it from wherever your program is initiated. Please provide full code if you want comments on your approach.

Comment: `code`public class arrayWords {

 Words wl = new Words();

 
 private String gamewords[] = {"dog","cat","coffee","tag", "godzilla", "gamera", "lightning","flash","spoon","steak","moonshine"};
 
    void setArray(){
 for (int i=0; i<gamewords.length; i++)
     wl.wordList[i].setWord(gamewords[i]);
     
   }`code`

Comment: @JohnCasey please update your main question if you have more code. It's fairly hard to read it in the comments. I updated my answer with an example, I hope thats what you're after.